# easter egg like research Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a research system by typing, so this will work like easter eggs. For example : I type "albert" on the website, and the Jquery script will scroll to the div with the id #albert.

First, do you think this is even possible?

I already try using keyup listener, but all the function is retrieving is numbers, maybe ASCII. I tried something like :

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    input += e.which;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() { input = ""; }, 500);
    goto();
});

function goto() {
    alert(input); // display only numbers
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($("#" + input).offset().top)
    },500);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close. Use `String.fromCharCode`:

```js
var input = "";
var timer = null;
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    input += String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() { input = ""; }, 500);
    goto();
});

function goto() {
    if (input == "albert") alert("Hello, Albert.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: or listen to the `key`property of the keyboardevent

Comment: @Amadan the setTimeout never runs ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik: It does for me. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Okay so now, letters are retrieved instead of unicode, but when I type albert, script don't scroll to #albert div. Any ideas?

Comment: If you copied my code literally, it's because I left it out as it wasn't really relevant to the question and would have made the example less clear. If you didn't, then I don't know; is there an error? What does your code look like?...

Comment: Yes, I admit my question was quite unclear. What I want : When i type albert on a page of my website, the page scroll directly to the div which id is #albert. What happens : Nothing, when I type albert. I hope it is clear enough now, btw the code looks exactly the same I post except the string.fromcharcode you corrected.

Comment: Ah, I see. `($("#" + input.toLowerCase()).offset().top)` since `evt.which` is giving codes of uppercase letters; you are expected to handle shifting yourself when listening to keyboard. http://jsbin.com/sesicijuja

Comment: It... Works! Thanks for the attention Amadan